# how to apply flatMapToPair on a given rdd?

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

I have a `JavaPairRDD<String, List<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>` named `rddA`. For example (after collecting `rddA`): `[(word1,[(187,267), (224,311), (187,110)]), (word2,[(187,200), (10,90)])]`. Thus, for example, `word1` is the key and value is `[(187,267), (224,311), (187,110)])]`.

How can I define the corresponding `JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<Integer>>` to get the following ouptput:

```
[(187, [267, 110, 200]), (224,[311]), (10,[90])]
```

So, the obtained `JavaPairRDD`includes three keys: `187, 224` and `10`.  And for example, the key `187` has `[267, 110, 200]` as a list value.

Comment: did you look at groupingBy?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: What you are asking for is not very clear. Could you describe the logic with words? And also tell us what you have tried?

Comment: @Oli checks plz

Comment: Figuring out what you are trying to do with only one record is quite difficult. Can you provide an example with 2 or 3 records in your RDD? Ideally, can you explain the logic as well?

Comment: @Oli check plz i whish it is more clear now. thank for your cooperation

Comment: Oh right, I understand what you want to do now

Comment: @Oli thank you your solultion works. But as i read we should not use groupbykey for large dataset so how can i modify your solution to use reduceByKey, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to flatten the list of tuples (second value of your tuple) and group by the first element of the tuple.

```java
JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<Integer>> result = rddA
                .flatMapValues(x -> x) // flattening the list
                .mapToPair(x -> x._2) // getting rid of the first key
                .groupByKey()
                .mapValues(x -> { // turning the iterable into a list
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    x.forEach(list::add);
                    return list;
                });
```

Comment: how can improve this solution by replacing groupByKey by reduceByKey/

Comment: That would only improve the solution if the goal was to filter the resulting lists. If you want to keep everything, `reduceByKey` will not help.